# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net

We are deploying one site asp.net 1.1  on  Windows Web Server2008 R2  running IIS 7.5  on standalone PC. it is  working perfectly on the 2003 machine.  The 2008 machine is the one giving below trouble;

We are getting below error message:

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.
Module: StaticFileModule
Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile

1.) We  have added the 'POST' verb in to the request permissions on the StaticFile Handler.

2.) [What causes an HTTP 405 "invalid method (HTTP verb)" error when POSTing a form to PHP on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400210/what-causes-an-http-405-invalid-method-http-verb-error-when-posting-a-form-t)
We  have tried various suggestions from other forums but none have worked, i would really appreciate some help

Comment: not too sure, but you may check the following link http://forums.iis.net/t/1176772.aspx, may be its a help

Comment: go into Firebug > Console > All > refresh page > click HTML > check the "Requested URL" ... if dealing with json objects, you will need to add a mime type for .json and a handler mapping for *.json

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses JSON objects and the "Requested URL" is a *.json file, do the following:

http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.UT_bw9aOR8E