# Getting 404/405 error on HTML / PHP contact form (linking issue?)

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

The form lives at [fictiveapp.com/](http://fictiveapp.com/) It's the second one with Name, Email, and Message.

I'm running into two issues.

1. 405 error - I 'resolved' this by adding a [trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400210/what-causes-an-http-405-invalid-method-http-verb-error-when-posting-a-form-t)
2. 404 error -  when adding the trailing slash to resolve the previous issue i get a 404 error instead. I'm very new to PHP and am unsure how I'm supposed to link the files. I thought it would be the same as linking all other html files on a site, apparently not.

I have all the index.html, html_form_send.php, and contactthanks.php all in the same top (1st) level directory, with 2nd level CSS, JS, Font, and Img folders

All relavent code is below

**HTML**

```
    <div class="8u 12u$(small)">
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<div class="row uniform 50%">
<div class="6u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
<div class="6u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
<div class="12u$"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="4"></textarea></div>
</div>
<ul class="actions">
<li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

**PHP from html_form_send.php**

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "Michael.kalmykov.88@gmail.com";
$EmailTo = "Michael@kovcreation.com";
$Subject = "from fictive site";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message']));

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php/\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

**PHP from contactthanks.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">

<head>
    <title>work already!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">


        <br /><br />


    <h1>Your message has been sent!</h1><br />

    <p><a href="index.html">Back to Site</a></p>

</div>

<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-68528-29";
urchinTracker();
</script>
```

I'm sure its something stupid and simple but I've been searching forums for hours now and can't seem to find the issue.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: try using php redirect instead of html

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting, headers are better than html meta tags. Keep in mind that you can use an header only when you haven't printed anything.

Here how you can use headers:

header("location: ./yourfile.html");

Also, some tips to create a correct file path

To redirect to a file in the same folder use
 "./filename.php"

To redirect to a file that is in an external directory you can use "../" to exit 1 dir. for example if my file is inside "/hello/file.php" and I wanna redirect to "/index.php" my path will be "../index.php"

Comment: Thank you for the information. The only way i know how to "call" the php file i need is through `<form... action="/html_form_send.php/">`  Where do I put the `$header('Location: './html_form_send.php);?`

Comment: The header is meant for the html_form_send.php instead of the meta http-equiv redirect. The form looks correct... Use: <form method="post" action="./html_form_send.php">... Also, when you are in php and open something like a print with " you can use the ' inside the print without using \" for example print "Hello 'user'" instead of print "Hello \"user\"". Keep in mind that the header is a function and not a variable like you posted in your comment. It should be header("Location: ./contactthanks.php")