# HTTP 405 error when submitting a PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, iis, http-status-code-405

I am managing a website of a camp, which has a form that lets you book a place there. The data from the form are then sent in an email using the PHP mail() method. I'm aware that this is probably not the best/safest solution, but I am not very experienced with PHP and so far it has worked. Recently, the form however started giving a 405 error on submit. Is it some issue with my PHP?

This is the html for the form:

```
    <div class="container" id="main"> 

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar_container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hlavni_navigace">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="padding-top:8px">
                        <img class="logo" src="../img/ejpovice_drawing_250.png">
                    </a>
                   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"  style="letter-spacing:-0.1px;">
                       Autocamp
                   </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hlavni_navigace" aria-expanded="false">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html" >Home</a></li>
                        <li style="width:20%"><a href="accommodation.html">Accommodation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="reservations.html" class="active">Reservations<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>   
                </div>
             </nav>
        <div class="objednavkovy_formular" style="margin-top:80px">
            <div class="vnitrni_formular">

                <form class="formular" method="POST" action='rezervace.php'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">First name and surname: *</label><br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input size="100" type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name..." required>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email address: *</label><br>
                           <div class="input-group">
                               <input size="100" type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="example@gmail.com" value="@" required>
                           </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefon">Phone number: </label><br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="telefon" id='telefon' class='form-control' placeholder='123456789'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="od">From *</label>
                        <label for="do" style="margin-left:21%;">To: *</label><br>
                           <div class="input-group">
                               <script>
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});

 $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});
</script>
                               <input type="text" name ="od" id="datepicker" size="100" style="height:0px;width:20%;" required>
                               <input type="text" name="do" id="datepicker2" size="100" style="height:0px;width:20%;margin-left:50px;" required>
                           </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="typ">Accommodation type: *</label><br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <select name="typ" style="color:#555;border:none;font-size:14px;padding:20px;" required>
                                <option value="nespecifikovano">--||--</option>
                                <option value="Karavan">Caravan</option>
                                <option value="Obyt_auto">Motorhome</option>
                                <option value="Stan">Tent</option>
                                <option value="Chata">Bungalow</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pocet-lidi">Number of guests:</label><br>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input name="pocet-lidi" type="text" class="form-control" style="width:38%;color:#555;">
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="poznamky">Notes:</label><br>
                        <div class="input-group" style="width:71%;">
                            <textarea cols="1" style="resize:none;padding-right: 12px;padding-left:12px;padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:6px;" rows="3" name="poznamky" id="poznamky" class="form-control" placeholder="Special requests - fridge ..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:15px;"> 
                   <?php
if ($success) {
    echo $success;
}
?>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
  </div>       
    </div>

</body>
```

And this is the PHP which handles the form

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "info@kemp.cz";
    $email_subject = "Reservation";


    function died($error) {

        echo "We are sorry but your form contains errors and cannot be sent. ";
        echo "The errors are the following: <br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix the errors in the form.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||
       !isset($_POST['poznamky']) ||
       !isset($_POST['od']) ||
       !isset($_POST['do'])) {
        died('We are sorry but the form contains a mistake.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $poznamky = $_POST['poznamky']; // required
    $od = $_POST['od'];
    $do = $_POST['do'];
    $typ = $_POST['typ'];
    $cislo = $_POST['telefon'];
    $host = $_POST['pocet-lidi'];
    $from_email_address = "no-reply-rezervace@kemp.cz";

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= "Your email address isn't valid.<br />";
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-zá-žÁ-Ž .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
        $error_message .= 'Your name is not written in a valid way.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    if(strlen($host) > 2){
        $error_message .= 'The number of guests is not valid. <br />';
    }
    $pocet_exp="/^[0-9]$/";
    if (!preg_match($pocet_exp,$host)){
        $error_message .= 'The number of guests is not valid. <br />';
    }
    $cislo_exp="/^[0-9]$/";
    if (!preg_match($cislo_exp,$cislo)){
        $error_message .= 'The phone number is not valid <br />';
    }


    $email_message = "Reservation confirmation:<br><br>";
    $email_message2 = "Hi, <br> this email confirms your following reservation at Autocamp:<br><br>";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Full name: ".clean_string($name)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Phone number: ".clean_string($cislo)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "From: ".clean_string($od)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "To: ".clean_string($do)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Accommodation type: ".clean_string($typ)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Number of guests: ".clean_string($host)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Notes: ".clean_string($poznamky)."<br>";

    $email_message2 .= "Full name: ".clean_string($name)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "Phone number: ".clean_string($cislo)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "From: ".clean_string($od)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "To: ".clean_string($do)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "Accommodation type: ".clean_string($typ)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "Number of guests: ".clean_string($host)."<br>";
    $email_message2 .= "Notes: ".clean_string($poznamky)."<br><br>";

    $email_message2 .= "Thank you for your reservation and see you soon!";


    $headers = 'From: '.$from_email_address."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"'."\r\n";


    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    @mail($email_from, $email_subject, $email_message2, $headers);
    header('Location: rezervace-success.html');

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes an HTTP 405 "invalid method (HTTP verb)" error when POSTing a form to PHP on IIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400210/what-causes-an-http-405-invalid-method-http-verb-error-when-posting-a-form-t)

Comment: Where is this `rezervace.php` file located?

Comment: both the html and the php are in the root folder